# CodeMirror custom showHint() call doesn't work

Tags: javascript, plugins, editor, wysiwyg, codemirror

Attempting to implement a custom `showHint` call for a spellcheck module. I've followed the [docs](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_show-hint) but calling `editor.showHint` appears to do nothing and returns `undefined`.

I figure there is something I am missing. Here is my sandbox code to test:

```
editor.on('cursorActivity', function() {
    var options = {
    from: editor.getDoc().getCursor(),
    to: editor.getDoc().getCursor(),
    list: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  };
  editor.showHint(options);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3wvcudqt/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, figured out my problem, per the docs:

> Finding hints is done with a hinting functions (the hint option), which is a function that take an editor instance and options object, and return a {list, from, to} object

Instead of passing `from`, `to`, and `list` into `showHint(options)`, they must be returned from a `hint` function passed into `showHint`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3wvcudqt/4/

```
editor.on('cursorActivity', function() {
  var options = {
    hint: function() {
      return {
        from: editor.getDoc().getCursor(),
          to: editor.getDoc().getCursor(),
        list: ['foo', 'bar']
      }
    }
  };
  editor.showHint(options);
});
```